# How to fix menus and windows in macOS 10.14.6 that do not show any items?

Tags: terminal, mojave, vi

I am using a 13-inch MacBook Pro with macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave) installed. I am trying to utilize the Terminal, however, I cannot see any information in the terminal window. For example if I type `vim` and press <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd>, I can see that the program is open; it's identified in the window title, but nothing is displayed.

I have tried to restart my computer but this had not effect. To make matters worse the Apple menu with the shutdown commands is now blank when I open it and I am unable to shut down the computer safely.

[image: Blank Terminal]

Comment: I don't think this is limited to just Terminal because it's happening in the menu bar as well.  Does it happen in other apps?  How did you install macOS (upgrade, clean install, came with the machine) and which MacBook Pro (year)?  Please [edit] your question with the requested details.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue. It turned out that my fonts were corrupted and I had to open Font Book and Restore Standard Fonts.